# On the connection of ODE's and control theory

Tags: control-theory

I have a hard time seeing where an ODE and its solution or a system of ODE's and its solution comes into play in control theory.

As far as I understand we generally consider som kind of mix of the "phase/state space" idea and the in- and out-put idea when we consider the control problem.

I cant find a worked example involving a box plot, the state space model and the ODE, where the states, in- and out-put etc are specified in detail. Most examples seem to just say that the equation describes this problem but not in which way.

I am therefore looking for such an example!

The state space model takes the following form in my book
\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x,u), y=h(x,u)
\end{equation}

Comment: Does your book describe a mass spring damper system as an example? that shall be typical...We could take $\vec{x} = (x,\dot{x})$ (where $x$ is the displacement) as two state variables which defines the "state of the system", so that the governing equation $m\ddot{x}+b\dot{x}+kx = u(t)$ can be converted to a state space model. (I could expand it to an answer if your book doesn't have that)

Comment: @LiChunMin it does!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Control theory concerns itself with dynamic systems. How are dynamic systems *classically* modelled? By a set of ordinary differential equations. Usually, the simplest type of control system you would encounter in a textbook on the subject matter is a spring-mass-damper system, as @Li Chun Min mentioned in the comments. Such a one-dimensional system, in an ideal world, would be governed by the following differential equation:

$$
M\frac{d^2y(t)}{dt^2} + C\frac{dy(t)}{dt} + Ky(t) = u(t) \quad\Rightarrow\quad M\ddot{y} + C\dot{y} + Ky = u
$$

You can think of it this way: if you apply a force $u(t)$ on the mass, its displacement will be $y(t)$. If you are wondering where this equation came from, it can be derived in *classical* mechanics by application of Newton's second law. The notation that I have used above is slightly different than what you would typically find in physics books: $m\ddot{x} + c\dot{x} + kx = f(x)$. This is because $f(t)$ and $x(t)$ are the *input* and *output* of your system, respectively, and they have their own notation in control theory. Finally, the transfer function of the system can be derived to be:

$$
G(s) = \frac{1}{Ms^2 + Cs + K}
$$

And now the output can be related to the input as follows:

$$
Y(s) = G(s)U(s)
$$

Now you can *control* your system, job done. Classical control, however, has limitations. For example, it gets tedious or nigh impossible to model systems with multiple inputs and outputs. Modern control uses state-space representation to get around those limitations. The idea is that the system has a new property called *state*, $x(t)$. The current state of the system and the input, $u(t)$, determine the next state, $\dot{x}(t)$. Likewise, the output, $y(t)$, depends on the current state and the input. Putting all of this information in equations yields the model in your question:

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= f(x,u) &= Ax + Bu\\
y &= h(x,u) &= Cx + Du
\end{align}
$$

Working with the same system as above (spring-mass-damper), you would have two state variables because the system is of second order. The state-space model would then be:

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x}_1 \\
\dot{x}_2
\end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & I \\
-M^{-1}K & -M^{-1}C
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ M^{-1}
\end{bmatrix} u \\
y &= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

And there you have it. The same system modelled both classically and in state-space.

Comment: Very nice. The leap that bothers me is in some sense what @Li Chun Min adress in his comment. I.e how these to representations are related. The book I am reading (Astrom and Murray) mentions that the first form you give  "was repalced" by the latter.

Comment: Here is a link, http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/books/AM05/pdf/am08-complete_22Feb09.pdf. Thier statement is on page 32

Comment: Sorry, I do not completely understand what you are asking. Is it how to translate a classical model to its state-space representation? Or perhaps the physical meaning of these representations? Be aware that the same system could be modelled in different ways when in comes to state-space. Not only do you have a choice of state variables, but there are different *forms* of the state-space representation.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how they are connected and how thier different parts are releted to eachothers representations.Differential equations have states etc aswell, but I cant seem to get things right here. Also I dont see a natural place for the $x$ or how the $x$ comes into play into the first differential equation. In the end these two diffrent things seem to be very diffrent and not at all the same, which I think the authors are impling them to be.

Comment: Both of them seem quite similar to me. They related a change in input to a change in output. Classically, this change is modelled as a differential equation, or a set thereof. Remember that differential equations are defined exactly for that purpose: to describe the rates of change of some quantities.

The state-space model is just a slightly different beast. By introducing an intermediate variable, namely the internal state, we are able to capture better the properties of the system. For example, ODE can describe only LTI systems.

Comment: At the end of the day, they are absolutely not the same thing, but they do describe the same thing. I think this is the crucial distinction.

Comment: right!! The ODE in $y$ is connected directly to the output while the state space model is related to change in $x$ which is not the output per say right?

Comment: Something like that, yes. In state-space, the output is dependent both on the internal state and on the input: $y = h(x,u)$. Therefore knowing a change in the input signal is not enough information to determine the change in the output. You also need to determine how the internal state has changed. But no matter how you model the system (ODE or state-space) an identical change in the input signal will result in the same change to the output of the system.